# How to simulate a phototransistor in a circuit, prefereably in ltSpice?

Tags: simulation, ltspice, infrared, phototransistor

I copied a circuit from a working pcb, which is detecting small IR intensity changes. I like to simulate it in ltSpice but I dont know how?!
notes on circuit:
the transistor is bc847, op amp is lm324, phototransistor longer pin (perhaps Emitter) is connected to IR-PHOTO++ [image]

Comment: The simplest is a NPN with a current source in the base. A quick search revealed [this](http://www.cel.com/pdf/appnotes/an3017.pdf) in the first results.

Comment: The application note mentioned above seems to no longer be available at that URL, but I was able to find this, which I think may be the same thing: https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/196/CEL_5F00_AN3017_5F00_Optocoupler_5F00_PSpice_5F00_Model.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are models of photo transistors on my webpage: http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/